# How to use cloudhsm java library

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jce, hsm, amazon-cloudhsm

In the Amazon CloudHSM command line tools there is the command `findKey` which can take a bunch of different parameters to search for keys by type, class, label etc.  The equivalent in the Java library would appear to be the `com.cavium.cfm2.Util.findKeys` methods.  There is no source, documentation or Javadoc for the classes in this library so it's impossible to know what the parameters to these methods actually signify.

What I'm trying to figure out how to do using the Java lib:

1. How to find keys based on type?
2. How to return all keys (`Utils.findAllKeys(null)` perhaps?)?

I've looked everywhere for some kind of Javadoc.  Would be bonus if someone knows if it exists somewhere.

Comment: What kind of keys are you trying to pull for what use-case?

Comment: I need to implement an API backed by CloudHSM (via the Java library) which will need to support calls such as list all keys, list all ec/rsa/aes keys, list keys that match the label XYZ etc.  Basically expose over the API a subset of the different ways of finding keys as the `findKey` command.